# Need a common term for walking around a barrier or obstacle

Tags: word-request

I need a word for walking around something.

Is "to circumvent something" a common term for walking around a barrier?

Comment: It depends on what type of barrier.

Comment: It could be a fence, an overturned tree, steep slope or dense vegetation that could not be passed...

Comment: Why? *walk around* is fine and commonly used.

Comment: ok, but when can I use circumvent?

Comment: @parallax : [circumvent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/circumvent) is typically used *figuratively*, in a sense of "avoiding" something, Example: You circumvent a rule or law, if you find a loophole so that you can do it nevertheless. The literally use is possible and valid, but may sound stilted. "Walk around" an object is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word `circumvent` is not so common in this situation. As user3169 said, using `walk around` is commonly used and works fine. You could use `go around` which is more casual.

You can also use these words in more formal situations:

- circumnavigate
- bypass

Comment: I guess you _could_ use circumnavigate (at least, that's what the dictionary says), but I usually associate that word with Magellan, not walking around a puddle or fallen tree.